# how do I convert a path string to controller + action + parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, actioncontroller, actiondispatch

(I'm sure I've seen the answer to this, but can't find it after many minutes of digging.  It should be an easy one to answer...)

### motivation

In the console, you can invoke the `get` method with a path argument, such as:

```
app.get posts_path(321)
```

This invokes `ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers#get`, which converts "/posts/321" into the appropriate controller and action and parameters, e.g. {:controller => "posts", :action => "show", :id => "321"}.

But you can't do that in controller tests.  To get the same effect, you'd need:

```
get :show, :id => "321"
```

This is because the `get` method is defined by `ActionController::TestCase#get`, which expects the action and parameters to be already parsed out.

I can write my tests where I manually fill in :controller, :action and any parameters, but that seems like a good way to introduce errors.

### the question

Is there a method that will parse a string (e.g. the invocation of `posts_path(321)`) into the appropriate :controller, :action and parameters, suitable for passing to `ActionController::TestCase#get`?

It would make writing tests simpler and less error-prone.

[EDIT: I realize that you need the HTTP verb (`get`) as well as the path (`/posts/321`) to uniquely map to the :controller and :action, but the question still stands...]